# C++ stylish GUI

Tags: c++, user-interface

I am trying to show future employers that I can do something with C++ (ironically I can't because I'm here).  I am trying to write a program that for starters tracks my purchases and stocks and bills and categories and possibly does graphs.  I want to do something related to my life that I may actually use.

I did a little investigation: Wt, cppCMS but am still confused

I want the program to look like Apple windows (in general) as opposed to the command window (black with boxy white letters)

Any help? What should I use?

Comment: The `interface` tag should be replaced by `gui` or similar.

Comment: Fixed.  A little confused about meaning of interface.

Comment: Hint: Don't just create one program in C++, create a multitude of programs. Try a couple GUI apps (perhaps including the one you mentioned), maybe some games or random projects to handle different data structures etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're ambitious, and *really* want it to look like Apple GUI (because it's really important), just go ahead and download Xcode, learn Mac programming from the online help at the Apple sites, and write a little app.  Will take a bit of time, though.  You'll have to use Objective-C and Objective-C++, though, and show that your C++ skills can be integrated with your Objective-C skills, to use the newer interfaces.  Or, you could use the older "Carbon" interfaces and stay in C++.

Otherwise, I'd use some popular GUI framework, such as QT or GTK+, then you can stay in C++. You'll also have a good template app to start with.

QT has a link to an Apple look-and-feel doc: 
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qtmac-as-native.html

You can use GTK+ and gain some Mac look-and-feel by linking with the GTK Quartz graphics libraries, which provide native graphics.  A link to starting info is here: http://www.gtk.org/download/macos.php

Comment: I meant Apple as a sleek GUI in general.  Sorry that that wasn't clear. Still good info, though.